# php code for increment date using for loop not working in update condition

Tags: php, mysql

table name - receipt_entry

Two textbox and 1 datepicker in my form

user enter

```
receipt      =  700
coupon       =  501,502,503,504,505,506
coupondate   =  28-02-2015
```

then 6 rows insert in database because there are 6 coupon in textbox and also 6 coupondate generates automatically with +1 month in every date.

After insert Runs data Insert  in table like below

```
receipt    coupon  coupondate
 700        501    27-03-2015
 700        502    27-04-2015
 700        503    27-05-2015
 700        504    27-06-2015
 700        505    27-07-2015
 700        506    27-08-2015
```

My problem is every thing goes well in insert query.

But when I try to update same thing all columns are update properly. But coupon and coupondate are not updating in incrementorder.

I try to update using receipt no because this is unique in database.

After UPDATE Runs data UPDATE in table like below

```
receipt    coupon  coupondate
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
```

Below is my code:

**EDIT LINK**

```
<a href="customer_entry.php?edit=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['receipt_no']); ?>" class="ico edit">Edit</a>
```

INSERT CODE

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/config.php');    
    if(!isset($_SESSION['Auth']['id'])) 
        {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        }            
    $errors = array();      
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {

                $receipt_no = $_POST['receipt_no'];             
                $coupon = $_POST['coupon'];                     
                $arr = explode(",", $coupon);
                $min = min($arr);
                $max = max($arr);                  
                $errors = $database->receipt_exists($receipt_no);
                    if(!count($errors))
                     {                                              
                            $startingdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['startingdate']));
                            for ($i = 1 ; $i <= count($arr) ; $i++) 
                            {
                                $count = 1;
                                for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++)
                                {       
                                $coupondate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate)) . " +" . $count . " month - 1days"));
                                $count++;   
    $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO receipt_entry (coupondate,receipt_no,coupon,startingdate)                        
VALUES(:coupondate,:receipt_no,:coupon,:startingdate)",array(':coupondate'=>$coupondate,':receipt_no'=>$receipt_no,':coupon'=>$i,':startingdate'=>$startingdate));                  
                                }
                            }                       
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Customer Created Successfully";                 
                    }    
        }               
?>
```

**UPDATE CODE**

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['update']))
        {           
                $receipt_no = $_GET['edit'];

                $receipt_no = $_POST['receipt_no'];                     
                $coupon = $_POST['coupon'];                     
                $arr = explode(",", $coupon);
                $min = min($arr);
                $max = max($arr);       
                $startingdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['startingdate']));   

            for ($i = 1 ; $i <= count($arr) ; $i++) 
            {
                $count = 1;
                for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++)
                {       
                $coupondate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate)) . " +" . $count . " month - 1days"));
                $count++;                                   
$updaterow = $database->updateRow("UPDATE receipt_entry SET coupondate=:coupondate,receipt_no=:receipt_no,coupon=:coupon,startingdate=:startingdate WHERE receipt_no = :receipt_no",
array(':coupondate'=>$coupondate,':receipt_no'=>$receipt_no,':coupon'=>$i,':startingdate'=>$startingdate,':receipt_no'=>$receipt_no));
                }
            }   

        }                   
?>
```

Comment: `$coupondate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate)) . " +" . $count . " month - 1days"));` <-- WOW

Comment: a lot of your date code is basically drunk. you're staggering between timestamp and strings like crazy. Your "source" values should ALWAYS be timestamps. you only convert to strings when it's display time. And you're storing those dates as strings in the db. That's almost always a bad idea. now you can't use mysql date functions on them, because they're not date/datetime fields.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **nested loop controller**.. use different var then **$i** for the second loop.

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= count($arr) ; $i++) 
{
  //....
  for ($j = $min; $j <= $max; $j++)
  {
     //.. .....:coupon'=>$j...
  }
}
```